# Running pytest and test the pytest_sessionfinish ,but its not getting invoked

Tags: pytest, prometheus

I want to invoke the pytest_sessionfinish method to get a rowcount of passed/failed tests and pass them to the prometheus gateway but no matter what I do this method is not getting invoked. Here is my code -

```
import pytest


@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def my_fixture():
    print("in fun")
    yield


def test_example(my_fixture):
    assert 2 + 2 == 4


@pytest.hookimpl(tryfirst=True)
def pytest_sessionfinish(session, exitstatus):
    print("pytest_sessionfinish called")
```

I also tried using the -s flag in case the print output was getting suppressed but that is also not helping.
Any pointers will be of help.

Tried turning on debug to see if there are any errors
Tried using -s and -v flags when running pytest
Tried on multiple environments but behavior is the same

Comment: From my reading of the documentation, hooks are only relevant if you're writing pytest plugins. If you need to run teardown code, use a session-scoped fixture.

Answer (score 0):

Move your hook to conftest.py, it seems that pytest can't discover a hook in test_*.py file